# Leer assets de una app desde una libreria (jar)

Tags: java, android

Que tal comunidad. A ver si alguien me dá una mano en esto. Sucede que estoy trabajando en organizar los códigos repetitivos y reutilizables en una librería propia y la intención es distribuirla en la fábrica en formato jar como es lo normal. Todo va bien pero tengo un caso particular con una de las clases que estoy migrando; tengo una clase que se encarga de escribir una serie de reportes de actividades del usuario del sistema (una especie de monitoreo), lo que deseo hacer es lo siguiente:
hacer configurable el nombre (entre otras cosas) del archivo de los logs, pensé en tomar esta configuración de un fichero json que se ubique en los assets del proyecto de quien use la librería, no en los assets de la librería.

**EDIT:** edito mi pregunta para que se entienda mejor

En cada cada clase que debe registrar eventos de uso se realiza una instancia del monitor de la siguiente manera:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Logit logger = Logit.getInstance(this.getClass());
...// onCreate(), etc ...
}
```

La instancia se realiza incluso desde clases que no extienden de Activity, por ejemplo desde un DataBaseHelper de SQLite.

El constructor de la clase Logit es el siguiente:

```
public static Logit getInstance(Class<?> clazz) {
    if (log == null)
        log = new Logit();

    try {
        AssetManager manager = Resources.getSystem().getAssets();
        InputStream is = manager.open("logit.cfg");
        String input = new Scanner(is, "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(input);
        String file = json.getString("filename");
        boolean showv = json.getBoolean("showAppVersion");
        log.setFileName(file);
        log.setShowVersion(showv);
        log.setClassName(clazz.getCanonicalName());
        return log;
    }catch(Exception e) {
        log.write(Logit.stringStackTrace(e));
        return log;
    }
}
```

Lo que me interesa es conservar el argumento realmente necesario al momento de la instancia (`Class<?>`) y por la ubicación de la línea de la instancia no me es factible ubicar referencias al `AssetManager` del app anfitrión para ubicar el recurso, por eso mi interés en encontrar la forma de ubicar la configuración repetible de manera silenciosa a través de un archivo de configuración.
La pregunta es ¿cómo puedo desde la librería tomar una configuración que existe en el proyecto que usa la librería, específicamente de los assets? no me agrada la idea de que el desarrollador tenga que abrir el jar para modificar las configuraciones a su gusto. Un ejemplo claro del objetivo es emular una configuración como la de log4j.
Saludos a todos!

Comment: Rosendo que tal con las respuestas? Comenta si alguna soluciona tu problema o si estas encallado en algún sitio.

Comment: Que tal, pues como el tema a quedado en segundo plano no he revisado las respuestas, pero si que las tengo en cuenta. En cuanto pueda las pruebo.

Comment: Por eso puse el bounty, a ver si lo solucionas ;)

Comment: jejejeje entiendo, la otra semana toco ese modulo nuevamente ya que forma parte de las migraciones que estoy realizando :)

Comment: Rosendo alguna novedad? Faltan 24 horas para finalizar la recompensa ;)

Comment: Estoy probando :) en cuanto tenga los resultados aviso!

Comment: Listo! problema resuelto gracias a @Ipman1971

Answer (score 4):

Creamos una clase para cargar la propiedades, yo lo he hecho para un fichero de tipo clave-valor como un properties, tu hazlo para un JSON:

```
public class PropertiesLoader { 
  private Context context;
  private Properties properties;

  public PropertiesReader(Context context) { 
    this.context = context;
    properties = new Properties();
  }

  public Properties getProperties(String fileName) {
    try {    
      //Accede al directorio asset 
      AssetManager am = context.getAssets(); 
      InputStream inputStream = am.open(fileName); 
      properties.load(inputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) { 
       //traza el error
    }
    return properties;
  }
}
```

Ahora adaptamos tu clase Logit para usar esta nueva clase

```
public static Logit getInstance(Class<?> clazz, Context context) {
  if (log == null)
    log = new Logit();

  try {
    PropertiesLoader loader=new PropertiesLoader(context);
    Properties logitProperties=loader.getProperties(logit.cfg);

    // :TODO cargar propiedades en logit
    //yo lo hize para un fichero tipo properties tu hazlo para un fichero JSON
    ......
    return log;
  } catch(Exception e) {
    log.write(Logit.stringStackTrace(e));
    return log;
  }
}
```

Esta clase sera la implementada por el desarrollador

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  //Añadimos el nuevo parametro al constructor
  Logit logger = Logit.getInstance(this.getClass(),this);
  ...// onCreate(), etc ...
}
```

Espero que te funcione.....

Comment: excelente! Ya ví el asunto del problema, lo que tenía que hacer era pasar el contexto de la aplicación sobre la que se ejecuta la librería, es decir; en lugar de esto `AssetManager manager = Resources.getSystem().getAssets();` solo pasar el context y ubicar los assets así `AssetManager am = context.getAssets();`

Comment: Habrá alguna manera de no incluir el `Context` dentro del `getInstance`? Lo que pasa es que esta no es una clase de uso exculsivo en activities, se debe poder usar en cualquier clase java, sea o no un `Activity`, tu respuesta resuelve mi problema, pero ahora tengo ese nuevo inconveniente. Intente con Resources.getSystem().getAssets()  pero no va, no son los assets que necesito, me comentas.

Answer (score 0):

He buscado por la red, prueba con eso

```
getResources().getIdentifier("res_name", "res_type", "com.library.package");
```

a `R.id.settings` se accede:

```
getResources().getIdentifier("settings", "id", "com.library.package");
```

Extraído de [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421244/accessing-application-resources-from-the-library-project/9421473#9421473)

Answer (score 0):

Quizá encuentres estos métodos útiles.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BufferedReader br;

    EditText editTextName;

    private final String FILENAME = "properties.xml";
    Properties properties;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.editTextName = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editTextName);

        this.loadAssetFile();
        this.loadRawFile();

        this.properties = new Properties();

        File file = new File(getFilesDir(), FILENAME);
        try {
            if(file.exists()) {
                FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(FILENAME);
                this.properties.loadFromXML(fis);
                fis.close();
            } else {
                this.saveToStorage();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void saveToStorage() throws Exception {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        this.properties.storeToXML(fos, null);
        fos.close();
    }

    public void saveToProperties(View v) {
        this.properties.setProperty("name", this.editTextName.getText().toString());
        Toast.makeText(this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void loadFromProperties(View v) {
        this.textViewName.setText("Welcome " + this.properties.getProperty("name") + "!");
    }

    public void loadAssetFile() {
        try {
            AssetManager manager = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
            InputStream is = manager.open("asset.txt");
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            this.br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String currentLine;
            if((currentLine = this.br.readLine()) != null)
                this.greetingAsset.setText(currentLine);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void loadRawFile() {
        try {
            InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.raw);
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            this.br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String currentLine;
            if((currentLine = this.br.readLine()) != null)
                this.greetingRes.setText(currentLine);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```